# WebKit WKWebView Error Handling

Tags: xcode, webkit, wkwebview

Please could someone advise with a example of Webkit WKWebView error handling...

I have the below working code (but without error handling) :

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var HybridWebView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")
        let requestUrl = URLRequest(url: url!)
        self.HybridWebView.load(requestUrl)
}
```

}

At the moment it will just display a blank page if web request has a error.

Comment: Use the delegates of `WKWebView`?

Comment: I found this code:

Comment: func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
  print("loading error", error)
 }

Comment: But where do I put it ? It doesn't seem to work.... Many thanks for the delegates direction just need last bit of help to implement it. ;)

Comment: You need to learn how to handle the delegate pattern in Swift. It’s a common one.

Comment: GOT IT ;) ... Many Thanks ..... Needed to add the delegates to the viewDidLoad().... 

HybridWebView.uiDelegate = self
HybridWebView.navigationDelegate = self

Comment: Thanks Larme for the push ;)